# Cornell Spider 2008

Tags: search

I'm trying to run Cornell Spider 2008 from the command line on Server 2012 R2, but not having much success.

```
Spider4.exe /run /L "c:\temp\spiderlog.log" /C: "e:\SpiderScans\spiderconfig.xml" /R: "c:\users"
```

If I put run at the front, it launches the GUI in unattended, but doesn't start the scan. I can then click the start button and it scans the path passed in.

If /run is at the end, the GUI starts, but not in unattended.

I've tried every variation on a theme I can think of, but nothing actually loads up Spider and starts the scan from the command line.

Comment: Where did you come up with the command line arguments? All I could find were `C:\path\spider.exe /run` or `C:\path\spider.exe /L C:\path\to\logfile`, but nothing with them combined. Have you tried the simple run command (without the additional arguments) to see if it will run unattended?

Comment: Here: https://confluence.cornell.edu/display/SSNREMOVAL/mail/112037801 and the source code. Fixed it now anyway. See my answer when I'm allowed to post it. Until then:
Couldn't find a way to get this to work with the downloaded binaries, so recompiled the source code with no changes under VS 2010 and it worked first time.

Looks like development on it is dead.

Comment: I wasn't able to find that before. That is helpful. What answer are you talking about?

Comment: The answer I wanted to post, but wasn't allowed to until 8 hours had passed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't find a way to get this to work with the downloaded binaries, so recompiled the source code with no changes under VS 2010 and it worked first time.

Looks like development on it is dead.

Comment: Development has been picked up by Columbia University. https://cuit.columbia.edu/content/cuspider-pii-scanning-application